# Take average over blocks Cuda

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

Cuda said that the shared memory can only be shared by data in the same block. But a block can only have at most 1024 threads. What if I have a huge matrix, and want to take average of them with maximized threads.

Takes this as an example. (I didn't use the maximized threads in one block, just as a demo)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void
kernel(int *a, int dimx, int dimy)
{
int ix = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
int iy = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;

int idx = iy * dimx + ix;

__shared__ int array[64];

a[idx] = a[idx] + 1;

array[idx] = a[idx];

__syncthreads();

int sum=0;
for(int i=0; i<dimx*dimy; i++)
{
    sum += array[i];
}

int average = sum/(dimx*dimy+1.0f);

a[idx] = average;

 }

int
main()
{
int dimx = 8;
int dimy = 8;
int num_bytes = dimx*dimy*sizeof(int);

int *d_a=0, *h_a=0; // device and host pointers
h_a = (int*)malloc(num_bytes);

for (int i=0; i < dimx*dimy; i++){
    *(h_a+i) = i;
}
cudaMalloc( (void**)&d_a, num_bytes );

//cudaMemset( d_a, 0, num_bytes );

cudaMemcpy( d_a, h_a, num_bytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

dim3 grid, block;
block.x = 4;
block.y = 4;
grid.x = dimx / block.x;
grid.y = dimy / block.y;

kernel<<<grid, block>>>(d_a, dimx, dimy);

cudaMemcpy( h_a, d_a, num_bytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );


std::cout << "the array a is:" << std::endl;
for (int row = 0; row < dimy; row++)
{
    for (int col =0; col < dimx; col++)
    {
        std::cout << h_a[row * dimx + col] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

free(h_a);
cudaFree(d_a);
}
```

I create four blocks, and want to the results to be average of all of them. Now the result is:

```
the array a is:
3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 
3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 
3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 
3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 
11 11 11 11 12 12 12 12 
11 11 11 11 12 12 12 12 
11 11 11 11 12 12 12 12 
11 11 11 11 12 12 12 12
```

Each block has its own average, rather overall average. How could I take the average over all the blocks?

I'm new to Cuda. Any relevant answer is welcomed.

Comment: Look at one of the reduction examples in the CUDA SDK to see how this kind of thing is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to launch multiple kernels, such that you do your per-block average, write those out to global memory, then launch another kernel to work on the per-block results from the previous kernel. Depending on your data dimensions you might have to repeat this multiple times.

e.g. (in pseudo-code)

```
template <typename T>
__global__ reduce(T* data, T* block_avgs)
{
    //find the per-block average, write it out to block_avgs
    //...
}

//in your caller:
loop while you have more than 1 block:
    call kernel using result from prev. iteration
    update grid_dim and block_dim
```

This is necessary as there's no inter-block synchronization in CUDA. Your problem is a pretty straightforward application of reduction. Take a look at the parallel reduction sample [at the nvidia samples page](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/) to get a better feel for reductions.